# Google Translate API has html entities in response...Is this normal

Tags: google-translate

I am using the google translate v2 paid API and I am getting back html entities in the response. Example:

English: `Login`
Italian: `Parola d&#39;ordine`

Why doesn't it return `Parola d'ordine`

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly mentioned in the doc, it looks like this is per specs. The jsonp example in the doc at https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#JSONP shows that the response from the translate API is added to the document as

```
target.innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

Which is safe only if translatedText is html-safe, with all entities encoded correctly. If you need the raw text, doing a entity-decode should be trivial.